# Change contents of cell based on date range in Google spreadsheet

Tags: google-sheets

I’m trying to get a cell to change its value based on a date range.

Let's say I have this list:

```
A        B
date1    10
date2    25
date3    50
date4    85
```

On date1 I will have 10 items, date2 I will have 25 etc.

What I’m trying to do is if today's date is after (or on) date1 but **before** date2, input date1's value from B. Then, once we hit date2, input date2's value from B.

Comment: Can you clarify this? Maybe publish a Google Spreadsheet that shows what you need? You may be able to use nested IF statements.

Comment: Not sure what I can provide beyond the snippet.

Comment: Basically, if I have an input of just today's date, and today's date is between date1 and date2, I need the formula to return "10" (B2). If today's date is between date2 and date3, I need the formula to return "25" (B3).

Comment: Are the dates sorted? So that `date1 < date2 < date3 < date4`?

Answer (score 1):

If I've understood the question correctly, you may use something like

```
=VLOOKUP(MAX(FILTER(A1:A; A1:A <= NOW())); A1:B; 2)
```

The formula `FILTER`s the date column, so that only dates `<= today` considered. The `MAX` function returns the latest of these dates. Then, the `VLOOKUP` returns the corresponding value from column `B` (the `2`nd column in the `A1:B` matrix).